# How to customize the hight of a bclogo box?

Tags: box, bclogo

Here are two `bclogo` boxes whose hights are not the same.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{columns}
    \column{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{bclogo}[logo=\bcquestion, couleurBarre=blue, noborder=true, 
        couleur=SkyBlue]{$\alpha$}
        \begin{equation*}
        \left\Vert x-y\right\Vert_{2}
        \end{equation*} 
    \end{bclogo}
    \column{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{bclogo}[logo=\bcquestion, couleurBarre=blue, noborder=true, 
        couleur=SkyBlue]{$\beta$}
        \begin{equation*}
        \sum\limits_{N}\left\Vert x-y\right\Vert_{2}
        \end{equation*} 
    \end{bclogo}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want to increase the hight of the left-hand side (thinner) box to become the same as that of the right-hand side (thicker) one. Searching "rembourrage" (padding) in the French manual of the package yielded nothing.

What is the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ad hoc solution, which is independent of `bclogo`, is to use a `\vphantom`.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table,usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{columns}
    \column{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{bclogo}[logo=\bcquestion, couleurBarre=blue, noborder=true, 
        couleur=SkyBlue]{$\alpha$}
        \begin{equation*}
         \vphantom{\sum\limits_{N}}\left\Vert x-y\right\Vert_{2}
        \end{equation*} 
    \end{bclogo}
    \column{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{bclogo}[logo=\bcquestion, couleurBarre=blue, noborder=true, 
        couleur=SkyBlue]{$\beta$}
        \begin{equation*}
        \sum\limits_{N}\left\Vert x-y\right\Vert_{2}
        \end{equation*} 
    \end{bclogo}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]